# I get "Service not available temporarily, please try it later." error from kucoin API

Tags: c#, .net, api, cryptocurrency

I write this code for placing order in kucoin:

```
            var client = new KucoinClient(new KucoinClientOptions()
            {
                FuturesApiOptions = new KucoinRestApiClientOptions
                {

                    ApiCredentials = new KucoinApiCredentials("629d76bxxxxxxx001dfdaef", "c8bd3ab2-xxxx-xxx-9ce2-5f40bd9fa0e3", "xxxxxxxxxxxx"),
                    AutoTimestamp = false
                }
            });

            var result = client.FuturesApi.Trading.PlaceOrderAsync("ETH Perpetual/USDT",
Kucoin.Net.Enums.OrderSide.Buy, NewOrderType.Limit, 1, 2, 4).Result;
```

but I get error `Service not available temporarily, please try it later.`
Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's an internal error because its status is `500`.